# What is wrong in this query?

Tags: mysql, sql

This query:

```
SELECT tbl_deliverable.*, user_to_deliverable.*
where tbl_deliverable.id = user_to_deliverable.d_id
```

returns this error from phpmyadmin:

> `#1064` - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near `'where tbl_deliverable.id = user_to_deliverable.d_id'` at line 1

Why?

Comment: Now that you have your answer, let's delete this question -- it is far too localized :)

Comment: @pst vote it to delete. I cannot as it is answered and commented :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot your "from tables" in the SQL:

```
SELECT tbl_deliverable.*,   user_to_deliverable.*
from   tbl_deliverable,     user_to_deliverable
where  tbl_deliverable.id = user_to_deliverable.d_id
```

Just add:

```
from tbl_deliverable, user_to_deliverable
```

Answer (score 4):

You have no `FROM` clause.

It should be

```
SELECT tbl_deliverable.*, user_to_deliverable.* 
FROM tbl_deliverable, user_to_deliverable                -- <== missing
where tbl_deliverable.id = user_to_deliverable.d_id
```

or do ANSI SQL-92

```
SELECT tbl_deliverable.*, user_to_deliverable.* 
FROM tbl_deliverable INNER JOIN user_to_deliverable               
         ON tbl_deliverable.id = user_to_deliverable.d_id
```